# Is it safe clear a Set in a loop if it finds the correct value?

Tags: java, loops, set

I'm in this situation: if I find a specific value in a HashSet, I have to update a field, clear the set and return the field.
Here one example:

```
static Set<Integer> testSet = new HashSet<>();
static Integer myField = null;        // the field could be already != null

public static int testClearSet()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {   // this is just for the test
        testSet.add(i);
    }
    for (Integer n : testSet) {
        if (n == 50) {
            myField = n;
            testSet.clear();
            return myField;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I'm wondering if doing this to the set it's safe, considering the fact that later on I should reuse the set.

I'm asking this, because I knew that to make changes over a Collection while iterating, is not a "good practice", but this case I think is a little bit different.

A possible solution would be:

```
boolean clear = false;
for (Integer n : testSet) {
    if (n == 50) {
        myField = n;
        clear = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (clear) {
    testSet.clear();
    return myField;
}
```

So, which one is the right way?

Comment: I think your solution it's ok, btw change the inner if return to n or 50, less code and you always return 50 there, so it's ok.

Comment: It is fine, only when that `iterator` would have been used after the `clear()` its internal state would not match with the Set, and likely a ConcurrentModificationException thrown by the iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ConcurrentModificationException` is only thrown if you continue iterating after changing it manually.

What you do is change it and abort iterating, so it should be 100% safe (regardless of the for-each implementation).

The real issue is, the readability of the code. A piece of code should ideally do one job, and if this job is complicated, split it up. In particular, your code has two parts, a condition and an action:

```
if (some condition) do some action
```

So:

```
public static int testClearSet() {
    if (setConatins(50)) {
        myField = 50;
        testSet.clear();
        return myField;
    }
    return -1;
}

private static boolean setConatins(int searchFor) {
    for (Integer n : testSet) {
        if (n == searchFor) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The latter method can be replaced with a single API call, for you to figure out.

Comment: Yeah, this was my first thought: since I'm interrupting the iteration just after the `testSet.clear()` everything should be fine, but then this doubt came out and so I asked. Thanks a lot for the readability advice, in fact, my real problem is a little bit more complex that simply "find 50" and so, the "split up" approach fits really well.

Answer (score 1):

It should be safe to remove elements from a set when using an explicit iterator.  Hence the following should be safe:

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator = testSet.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Integer element = iterator.next();
    if (element.intValue() == 50) {
        testSet.clear();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your `Set` changing only in one thread, so you can clean it like in first example.

Method `clear()` does not throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 0):

Both your code will work.

There is indeed a restriction in modifying the collection when u iterate using fail fast iterators. That means, iterating using fail fast iterator will fail if there is any modification in the collection after the iterator was created. All the default iterators that is returned by java collection classes are fail-fast iterators.

```
private void removeDataTest (Collection<String> c, String item) {
    Iterator<String> iter = c.iterator(); //Iterator is created.
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
         String data = iter.next();
         if (data.equals(item)) {
             //c.remove(data); //Problem. Directly modifying collection after this iterator is created. In the next iteration it will throw concurrent modification exception.
             iter.remove(); //This is fine. Modify collection through iterator.
             //c.clear(); break; //This is also should be okay. Modifying the collection directly, but after that it is breaking out and not using the iterator.
         }
    }
}
```

In your code, u don't continue iteration after the set is modified. So should be fine.